# Validation error not displayed CakePHP

Tags: validation, error-handling, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to display validation errors with CakePHP (Newbie) but I'm stuck. I get this error "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash". Don't know if the logic is respected, I'm starting from scratch.

Nothing is displayed. Here's my code:

**User model**

```
class User extends AppModel {
public $validate = array(
    'nom' => array(
            'message' => 'Saisie obligatoire',
            'required' => true
        ),
    'prenom' => array(
            'message' => 'Saisie obligatoire',
            'required' => true
    ),
    'date_naissance' => array(
            'rule' => array('date','dmy'),
            'message' => 'Veuillez respecter le format de la date     (jour/mois/année)',
            'allowEmpty' => true
    ),
    'email' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message' => 'Veuillez introduire une adresse mail valide',
            'required' => true
        ),
    'password' => array(
            'rule' => 'password',
            'message' => 'Un mot de passe est requis'
        )
);

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] =     AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

**add function into UsersController**

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->set($this->request->data);
            if ($this->User->validates()) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Auth->login($this->User);
                return $this->redirect('/index');
            }
        }
    } else {
        return $this->User->validationErrors;
    }
}
```

**add.ctp**

```
<?= $this->element('navbar');?>

<div class="formcontainer">
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Rejoignez-nous</h1>
</div>
<form action="/users/add" id="UserAddForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input text">
        <label for="UserNom">Nom:</label>
        <input name="data[User][nom]" maxlength="20" type="text" id="UserNom" class="form-control" placeholder="requis">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input text">
        <label for="UserPrenom">Prénom:</label>
        <input name="data[User][prenom]" maxlength="20" type="text" id="UserPrenom" class="form-control" placeholder="requis">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input text">
        <label for="UserDateNaissance">Date de naissance:</label>
        <input name="data[User][date_naissance]" maxlength="20" type="text" id="UserDateNaissance" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input email">
        <label for="UserEmail">Email:</label>
        <input name="data[User][email]" maxlength="100" type="email" id="UserEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="requis"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group input password">
        <label for="UserPassword">Mot de passe:</label>
        <input type="password" name="data[User][password]" class="form-control" id="UserPassword" placeholder="requis">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default bSub">M&#039;inscrire</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use cakephp coding style for your `add.ctp` or you can achieve this by passing errors messages from your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation should be like this(You must add rule for field and there is no inbuilt *passowrd* rule in cakephp).

```
public $validate = array(
    'nom' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty', //add rule here
        'message' => 'Saisie obligatoire',
        'required' => true
    ),
    'prenom' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty', //add rule here
        'message' => 'Saisie obligatoire',
        'required' => true
    ),
    'date_naissance' => array(
        'rule' => array('date', 'dmy'),
        'message' => 'Veuillez respecter le format de la date     (jour/mois/année)',
        'allowEmpty' => true
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'rule' => 'email',
        'message' => 'Veuillez introduire une adresse mail valide',
        'required' => true
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty', //there is no inbuilt validation rule with name *password*
        'message' => 'Un mot de passe est requis'
    )
);
```

If you want to show error message then you should use Form Helper for create form inputs like this

```
echo $this->Form->input("User.nom", array("class"=>"form-control", "placeholder"=>"requis", 'label'=>false));
```

Or you can display message by using isFieldError method of Form helper

```
if ($this->Form->isFieldError('nom')) {
echo $this->Form->error('nom');
```

}

Answer (score 1):

// Model

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(

        'password' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Un mot de passe est requis'
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => array('email'),
                'message' => 'Veuillez introduire une adresse mail valide',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'date_naissance' => array(
            'date' => array(
                'rule' => array('date'),
                'message' => 'Veuillez respecter le format de la date     (jour/mois/année)',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'prenom' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Saisie obligatoire',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'nom' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Saisie obligatoire',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );
    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] =     AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

// Controller

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

// add.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add User'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('date_naissance');
        echo $this->Form->input('prenom');
        echo $this->Form->input('nom');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul>

        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]